# Installation of SpacCy Language Model in python not working

Tags: python, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I'm following the Rasa Core "Building a simple Bot" tutorial. (https://core.rasa.com/tutorial_basics.html) It requires the installation of the SpaCy Language model:

python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

However, I get "AttributeError: module 'thinc.linalg' has no attribute 'Mat'"

Have you any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Could you run `pip list` and check which versions of spaCy, Thinc and numpy you have installed? It's possible that something is incompatible here and/or didn't install correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest Spacy has a requirement of **thinc** as:

```
thinc>=6.10.1,<6.11.0
```

Double check the requirements.txt and check which modules are installed with pip list. If the issue is with incorrect version of thinc then run

```
pip uninstall thinc
pip install thinc==6.10.1
```